# Is it possible to display alternative text for selected items in a Select2 MultiSelect?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

I am using a Select2 MultiSelect with a set of grouped options:

Group 1:

- Option 1
- Option 2

Group 2:

- Option 1
- Option 2

etc.

When an option is selected (and thus shown in the input field) it would be great if the selected options cloud be distinguished by a group prefix, as in

"G1: Option 1, G2: Option 1"

Is this possible using Select2 (possibly by means of providing alternative text for each option item)?

Comment: it is possible using jquery multiple select here [MultipleSelect](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#multiple-select)

Comment: MultipleSelect seems to be able to do something similar, yes. Using Select2 is a requirement in my case though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an additional data attribute for the options and prepending this to the selected items:

```
$(".select2prefixselected").select2({
    templateSelection: format,
    escapeMarkup: function(m) {
        return m;
    },
});
```

With the following format function:

```
function format( item ) {
    element = $(item.element);
    text = item.text;
    prefix = element.attr('data-prefix');
    if (prefix) {
        prefix = prefix + ' ';
    }
    return prefix + text;
}
```